# how to get id from looping on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

*my browser showing message like this, because i'am lopping button with onclick function().
is there any other solution??*

Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function
at chrome-extension://cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip/js/notification.js:154:10

my code html with some blade looping from laravel

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="gender">
    <table class="table" id="genders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
                <th>Is Active</th>
                <th colspan="3">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($genders as $gender)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $gender->jenis_kelamin }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gender->is_active }}</td>
                <td width="120">
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <a href="{{ route('genders.show', [$gender->id]) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
                            <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{{ route('genders.edit', [$gender->id]) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>

                        <button class='hapus btn btn-danger btn-xs' id='hapus' onclick="hapus(<?= $gender->id  ?>)"><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

my js code. get id from lopping and make ajax call

```
function hapus(genderId) {
        bootbox.confirm("Do you really want to delete record?", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url("api/genders/") }}' + '/' + genderId,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    type: "DELETE",
                    data: genderId,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr, response) {
                        // alert(true === 1);
                        if (data.success == true) {

                            $('#gender').load(" #genders-table", function() {
                                alert("data berhasil di hapus")
                            })

                        } else {
                            bootbox.alert('Record not deleted.');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - Please show HTML and not server code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not from YOUR code but from a Chrome extension called "WhatRuns"

Also IDs need to be unique so I strongly recommend to delegate the click from the container and use data-attribute for the id

```js
document.querySelector("#genders-table tbody").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".hapus");
  if (tgt) {
    const genderId = tgt.dataset.genderid;
    console.log(genderId)
    bootbox.confirm("Do you really want to delete record?", function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url("api/genders/") }}' + '/' + genderId,
          dataType: "JSON",
          type: "DELETE",
          data: genderId,
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr, response) {
            // alert(true === 1);
            if (data.success == true) {
              $('#gender').load(" #genders-table", function() {
                alert("data berhasil di hapus")
              })
            } else {
              bootbox.alert('Record not deleted.');
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive" id="gender">
  <table class="table" id="genders-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
        <th>Is Active</th>
        <th colspan="3">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Bla 1</td>
        <td>Bla 1.1</td>
        <td width="120">
          <div class='btn-group'>
            <a href="#" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
              <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>

            <button class='hapus btn btn-danger btn-xs'  data-genderid="<?= $gender->id  ?>"><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Bla 2</td>
        <td>Bla 2.1</td>
        <td width="120">
          <div class='btn-group'>
            <a href="#" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
              <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
            </a>

            <button class='hapus btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-genderid="<?= $gender->id  ?>"><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: better do `const tgt = e.target.closest(".hapus");` and just `if(tgt){...` or `tgt` may point to any node inside the button and the condition will fail.

Comment: @Thomas First thing is a good idea, second comment is not true, if you click anything, it will not have the right classlist

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you sir.. the code works and it's so much better... thanks

Comment: @Thomas, Thank you for the advice, increase my knowledge

Comment: Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function is about extension called "WhatRuns". Many thanks for the advice! I had the same error on the Chrome and I couldn't solve it until find your answer.